# css with links

Tags: html, css, class, colors, hyperlink

I am assisting with the creation of a new website and tend to run into simple errors as I go. The following code is being used to style a link:

```
a.homepage-employment,
a:visited.homepage-employment {
display:block;
padding:5px;
background-color:#055830;
color:#fff;
width:100%;
}

a:hover.homepage-employment {
display:block;
padding:5px;
background-color:#999966;
color:#fff;
}
```

I am wondering why the background-color appears properly, but the text is not white when they are in the same class. Does the text color need to be within a separate class? I know I'm obviously missing something. Something most likely simple.

This is probably a very simple question, but I'm a beginner learning as I go. I appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i think your second group should be

```
a.homepage-employment:hover 
{ .... }
```

Proper form is: selector.class:pseudo-class {property:blah}

Comment: The same is true for your :visited pseudo-class in the first selector.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
a.homepage-employment {
    display:block;
    padding:5px;
    background-color:#055830;
    color:#fff;
    width:100%;
}

a.homepage-employment:hover {
    background-color:#999966;
}
```